# Css анимация "поворот страницы"

Tags: анимация, css

Здравствуйте, в [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/matritsa-preobrazovanii) написано что нельзя сделать [вот так](http://htmlbook.ru/files/images/blog/matrix_1d.png) ,с помощью [matrix](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/matritsa-preobrazovanii).
Но как же это тогда вообще возможно сделать?
Я видел такое не раз!
Вот например: [сайт](http://akuma.su/) ,при наведении на левую полосу мы увидим эту анимацию.
Как это возможно подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Это можно сделать по средствам jquery. Я только что заглянул в исходники странички, так там за это отвечает отдельный скрипт с прописанной в нём анимацией. в css чистом сделать подобное на самом деле нельзя.

Comment: Хорошо пусть это будет с помощью jQuery, всё равно какой анимацией я смогу это сделать?
Я долго думал над этим ,нечего придумать не смог.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjHkC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, держите: [клик](http://jsfiddle.net/n1r2gxnL/).

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="view" class="tacb">Ваш текст, сэр!</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#view {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-25deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-25deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-25deg);
    transform: rotateY(-25deg);
    height: 100px;
    background: url(http://akuma.su/bundles/ablog/i/bg.png) repeat;
    padding: 15px;
}
#wrap {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    -ms-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Обратите внимание на свойство perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ выше работать не будет, как и сказали, из-за того, что на чистом CSS повторить эффект сайта не получится.

```
$('#menu-handler').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $body.addClass('menu-visible');
});

$('#view').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $body.removeClass('menu-visible');
});

$('#view').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $body.removeClass('menu-visible');
});
```

Я и есть владелец указанного сайта. Помимо указанных выше стилей используется такой вот скрипт.